# Get new worksheet from clicking a button

Tags: excel, vba

so currently i have this code that loops through a folder of mine specified by me and goes through every single file in the folder to extract Ranges "A18,A19,A14" and copy it to the current worksheet.

However now i need to change the way it works, now i would like to have a main sheet that contains the button to generate the coding that i have written as shown below but in a new sheet. 
So basically what i need now is to have a main control sheet that only contains buttons , then do changes to the coding so that it creates a new sheet and generate the data there in the new sheet instead of the main control sheet.

Here is the image for the control sheet

[Starting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aooyU.jpg)

And here is the end result i wish to get

[What i need to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEU9o.jpg)

Also, i have tried myself before asking this question on adding new sheets however it doesn't work 
,here is the image of it

[Not Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdJJQ.jpg)

Somehow it just extracts from one file when its supposed to extract 6 lines as shown in the "What i need to see" Picture.

I really appreciate any help, but if possible pls provide me the small part of the code needed to make this work!

Here is what i have currently

```
Sub ScanFiles()

    Dim myFile As String, path As String
    Dim erow As Long, col As Long

    path = "c:\Users\Desktop\Tryout\"
    myFile = Dir(path & "")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Range("A2:I20").ClearContents
    Range("A1") = "Test"
    Range("B1") = "Temp"
    Range("C1") = "Start"
    Range("D1") = "Type"

    Do While myFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (path & myFile)
        Windows(myFile).Activate

        ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"
        Set copyrange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A18,A19,A14,A19")

        Windows("Reset.xlsm").Activate
        erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        col = 1

        For Each cel In copyrange
            cel.Copy
            Cells(erow, col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            col = col + 1
        Next

        Windows(myFile).Close savechanges:=False
        myFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Debug.Print myFile

    Range("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) ALWAYS use `Option Explicit` at the top of your code 2) FORMAT, format, format By formatting your code it makes things easier to read. 3) Declare your variables/worksheets/workbooks 4) to add a worksheets -> `Worksheet.Add`

Comment: ps. I just editted your code format. A little formatting goes a long way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here try this.. Something I quickly wrote (busy at work). I have made a few assumptions being the Folder you loop thru has only the excel files you need to loop over. 2nd assumtion is each file only has 1 tab. These 2 assumptions are easily fixed if wrong.

I have made reference to `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` for `FSO`. `DIR` is a dead, I only ever use `FSO` as it much more useful and you can nest `FSO` loops (something you can't do with `DIR`)

Also included is an array to store your `CopyRange` to we can make you code nater and use a single `For Loop`.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScanFiles()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets.Add
    wks.Name = "NewWorksheet"

    ' Add Worksheet to accept data
    With wks
        '.Range("A2:I20").ClearContents -> No longer needed as you create a new sheet
        .Range("A1:D1") = Array("Test", "Temp", "Start", "Type")
    End With

    ' Set your copy ranges
    Dim CopyRange(1 To 4) As String
    CopyRange(1) = "A18"
    CopyRange(2) = "A19"
    CopyRange(3) = "A14"
    CopyRange(4) = "A19"

    ' Early Binding - Add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" Reference
    Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    ' Set FolderPath
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "c:\Users\Desktop\Tryout\"

    ' Set Folder FSO
    Dim Folder As Scripting.Folder
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    ' Loop thru each file -> Assuming only 6 files as per you question
    Dim File As Scripting.File
    For Each File In Folder.Files

        Dim wkbData As Workbook
        Set wkbData = Workbooks.Open(File.path)

        Dim wksData As Worksheet
        Set wksData = wkbData.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' -> Assume this file has only 1 worksheet

        Dim BlankRow As Long
        BlankRow = wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 4
            wks.Cells(BlankRow, i).Value = wksData.Range(CopyRange(i)).Value
        Next i

        wkbData.Close False

    Next File

    Range("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! really thank you so much for spending ur time to write this code for me i really appreciate it VERY MUCH, you helped me big time! however there's just 2 questions that i need to clarify with you with, 1) how can i get all the file names e.g 6 files in the folder and write it into the new created worksheet right beside the copied ranges with the same format? Header=E1 and the filename from E2 onwards. 2) Is there a way to search for strings/words in all of the files in the folder and do the same thing again which is extract them into the new created sheet as well in the same format

Comment: I don't mean to take you for granted or anything!!! i really appreciate your help it seriously did help me!

Comment: Does the above code answer your original question? If so could you please approve/tick.    If this does answer your question, the website rules say you will need to create a new question asking the questions raised above. I will happily answer them for you as it is a simple task.

Comment: Yes it does answer my original question, i have approved it , sorry i didn't know about the rules... so i will have to create a new question?

Comment: Thanks. Could you upvote to please - this helps my rating. Yes you will need to start a new question - the reason is if someone searches for a similar issue, but the code I provided answers a question that has morphed from the original, this would throw that person off.. Thus, start a new question, use my code and we can help you ammend with whatever you need.

Comment: I have upvoted this answer, if you are free and able to help, here's the link to the new question! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988992/search-for-strings-words-filename-and-extract-into-new-sheet-using-fso

Comment: Thanks. Responded to your new question. :)