# Search for strings/words, filename and extract into new sheet using fso

Tags: excel, vba

I have previously asked an question related to this new question i am posting and with the help of a fellow mate, so what it does is it loops through a folder and extracts the specified range into a newly created excel sheet. However there's still 2 problems i'm facing,

1) how can i get all the file names e.g 6 files in the folder and write it into the new created worksheet right beside the copied ranges with the same format? Header=E1 and the filename from E2 onwards.

2) Is there a way to search for strings/words in all of the files in the folder and do the same thing again which is extract them into the new created sheet as well in the same format

Here is the code

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScanFiles()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets.Add
    wks.Name = "NewWorksheet"

    ' Add Worksheet to accept data
    With wks
        '.Range("A2:I20").ClearContents -> No longer needed as you create a new sheet
        .Range("A1:D1") = Array("Test", "Temp", "Start", "Type")
    End With

    ' Set your copy ranges
    Dim CopyRange(1 To 4) As String
    CopyRange(1) = "A18"
    CopyRange(2) = "A19"
    CopyRange(3) = "A14"
    CopyRange(4) = "A19"

    ' Early Binding - Add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" Reference
    Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    ' Set FolderPath
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "c:\Users\Desktop\Tryout\"

    ' Set Folder FSO
    Dim Folder As Scripting.Folder
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    ' Loop thru each file -> Assuming only 6 files 
    Dim File As Scripting.File
    For Each File In Folder.Files

        Dim wkbData As Workbook
        Set wkbData = Workbooks.Open(File.path)

        Dim wksData As Worksheet
        Set wksData = wkbData.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' -> Assume this file has only 1 worksheet

        Dim BlankRow As Long
        BlankRow = wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 4
            wks.Cells(BlankRow, i).Value = wksData.Range(CopyRange(i)).Value
        Next i

        wkbData.Close False

    Next File

    Range("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help! would be even better if able to provide small part of the code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `FSO` has some great features. One of them is `.Name`. Straight after this line:

```
For Each File In Folder.Files
```

Write:

```
Debug.Print File.Name
```

In the immeadiate window you will see the name of the file. You can then copy the result to a worksheet by simple reference, like this:

```
wks.Range("E1").Value = File.Name
```

And the header simply ammend this line:

```
.Range("A1:D1") = Array("Test", "Temp", "Start", "Type")
```

2) To search for words the quickest and easiest is to use the like function. Again you would use the same method as before but using an `If` statement.

```
If File.Name Like "*SomeString*" Then
    wksFSO.Cells(1, 1) = File.Name
End If
```

Note the use of wildcard `*` before and after the sear string. Modify this as you like. Its obvious I have the results pointing to a single cell. If you expect many then you can update this to write to a new line if more results are expected. To extract them to a new `Worksheet` I'd first set up the `Worksheet` and copy the names. Like this:

```
Worksheets.Add
```

Now to wrap all this up into the same code it could be written like:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScanFiles()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets.Add
    wks.Name = "NewWorksheet"

    ' New worksheet for question 2
    Dim wksFSO As Worksheet
    Set wksFSO = Worksheets.Add
    wksFSO.Name = "FSOWorksheet"

    ' Add headers data
    With wks
        .Range("A1:E1") = Array("Test", "Temp", "Start", "Type", "FileName")
    End With

    ' Set your copy ranges
    Dim CopyRange(1 To 4) As String
    CopyRange(1) = "A18"
    CopyRange(2) = "A19"
    CopyRange(3) = "A14"
    CopyRange(4) = "A19"

    ' Early Binding - Add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" Reference
    Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    ' Set FolderPath
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "c:\Users\Desktop\Tryout\"

    ' Set Folder FSO
    Dim Folder As Scripting.Folder
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    ' Loop thru each file -> Assuming only 6 files
    Dim File As Scripting.File
    For Each File In Folder.Files

        ' If loop looking for specific files and copy to new FSOWorksheet
        If File.Name Like "*SomeString*" Then
            wksFSO.Cells(1, 1) = File.Name
        End If

        Dim wkbData As Workbook
        Set wkbData = Workbooks.Open(File.Path)

        Dim wksData As Worksheet
        Set wksData = wkbData.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' -> Assume this file has only 1 worksheet

        Dim BlankRow As Long
        BlankRow = wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 4
            wks.Cells(BlankRow, i).Value = wksData.Range(CopyRange(i)).Value
        Next i

        ' Write filename in col E
        wks.Cells(BlankRow, 5).Value = File.Name

        wkbData.Close False

    Next File

    Range("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! so sorry for the late reply, and really thanks so much for the respond, however i'm not  just looking for specific files but also specific words/strings then extract it out continuing the row e.g "Smart" is the word i want to search for and extract :( may i know how it would the coding would be like?

Comment: you can modify this line `If File.Name Like "*SomeString*" Then` If you only want to run the code on that file then move the loop inside the `IF` statment.

Comment: hi, really thank you for the response, however the code you provided me covered my first question , and now i need to search for strings inside the file, which is question 2, so with your coding ``` If File.Name Like "*SomeString*"  Then ``` i wonder how i can change it so that it would not look for FileName but instead the strings inside the file and extract it out in the same format as the rest?

Comment: You need to open the file to search.

Comment: i'll mark it as an answer for the first part for searching the file part, however i'm still not sure how to search for strings inside the file

Comment: This question should help if you want to search "within" a file not just the file.name https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40553281/vba-that-searches-for-a-string-in-all-the-files-inside-a-folder-and-its-subfolde