# Find String and extract in vba using fso

Tags: excel, vba

so my code currently goes through a folder and extracts Ranges of data from every file in the folder into a format set by me, it also extracts the filename. 
Now i need to use fso to search for certain string inside the file not the filename, lets say "Smart", and in the file "Smart" appears quite a few times, but i only want to extract it once.

Thank you so much to anyone who is able to provide me the small part of the code or some advices to help me continue on!

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScanFiles()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets.Add

    ' New worksheet for question 2
    Dim wksFSO As Worksheet

    ' Add headers data
    With wks
        .Range("A1:E1") = Array("Test", "Temp", "Start", "Type", "FileName", "Test", "EndDate", "Smart", "Er")
    End With

    ' Set your copy ranges
    Dim CopyRange(1 To 4) As String
    CopyRange(1) = "A18"
    CopyRange(2) = "A19"
    CopyRange(3) = "A14"
    CopyRange(4) = "A19"

    ' Early Binding - Add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" Reference
    Dim FSO As New Scripting.FileSystemObject

    ' Set FolderPath
    Dim FolderPath As String
    FolderPath = "c:\Users\Desktop\Tryout\"

    ' Set Folder FSO
    Dim Folder As Scripting.Folder
    Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder(FolderPath)

    ' Loop thru each file -> Assuming only 6 files
    Dim File As Scripting.File
    For Each File In Folder.Files

        ' If loop looking for specific files and copy to new FSOWorksheet
        If File.Name Like "ReportFile" Then
            wksFSO.Cells(1, 1) = File.Name
        End If

        Dim wkbData As Workbook
        Set wkbData = Workbooks.Open(File.Path)

        Dim wksData As Worksheet
        ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1"
        Set wksData = wkbData.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' -> Assume this file has only 1 worksheet

        Dim BlankRow As Long
        BlankRow = wks.Range("A" & wks.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 4
            wks.Cells(BlankRow, i).Value = wksData.Range(CopyRange(i)).Value
        Next i

        ' Write filename in col E
        wks.Cells(BlankRow, 5).Value = File.Name

        wkbData.Close False

    Next File

    Range("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Search for strings/words, filename and extract into new sheet using fso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58988992/search-for-strings-words-filename-and-extract-into-new-sheet-using-fso)

Comment: Since you have the file loaded in a worksheet you can use Find() to locate your search terms.

Comment: is it possible for you to provide an example? thank you so much

Comment: http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/

Answer (score 1):

This could help you, what it does is it search through the path's folders and each excel file that is inside it for the word that you are going to put in the input box.

```
Sub SearchFolders()
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim fld As Object
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wOut As Worksheet
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim strFirstAddress As String

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Change as desired
    strPath = "c:\MyFolder"

    'You can enter your smart word here 
    strSearch =  inputbox("Please enter a word to be searched.","Search for a word") 

    Set wOut = Worksheets.Add
    lRow = 1
    With wOut
        .Cells(lRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(lRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(lRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(lRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set fld = fso.GetFolder(strPath)

        strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.xls*")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open _
              (Filename:=strPath & "\" & strFile, _
              UpdateLinks:=0, _
              ReadOnly:=True, _
              AddToMRU:=False)

            For Each wks In wbk.Worksheets
                Set rFound = wks.UsedRange.Find(strSearch)
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    strFirstAddress = rFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If rFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        lRow = lRow + 1
                        .Cells(lRow, 1) = wbk.Name
                        .Cells(lRow, 2) = wks.Name
                        .Cells(lRow, 3) = rFound.Address
                        .Cells(lRow, 4) = rFound.Value
                    End If
                    Set rFound = wks.Cells.FindNext(After:=rFound)
                Loop While strFirstAddress <> rFound.Address
            Next

            wbk.Close (False)
            strFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
    MsgBox "Done"

ExitHandler:
    Set wOut = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing
    Set wbk = Nothing
    Set fld = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub
```